# Make request with custom headers (POST)

Tags: php, curl, header

My code isn't working, tried a few things but I'm new to php so yeah... here's what I got, always returns me a blank page.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$rnd = $_GET['rnd'];
$ch = curl_init("http://chat.website.com/script/login.php?rnd=".$rnd);
$request_headers = array();
$request_header[] = (
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36',
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'onLoad: [type Function]',
'p: password',
'u: username',
'owner: [object Object]
');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
$userdata = curl_exec($ch);
echo $userdata;
?>
```

Comment: white page of death, error reporting\display are off, turn them on `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure `$array[] = (n1,n2,n3...)` is incorrect syntax

Comment: Delete everything between `$request_headers = array(` and `'User-Agent:...`

Comment: You haven't assigned anything to `$request_headers`. your `$request_headers` is a blank array as per the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error, I wasn't making the request in POST. 
Here's the code that is working if anyone needs it:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$rnd = 1;
$rnd = $_GET['rnd'];
$ch = curl_init("http://chat.website.com/scripts/login.php?rnd=".$rnd);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "onLoad=%5Btype%20Function%5D&p=password&u=username&owner=%5Bobject%20Object%5D");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$userdata = curl_exec($ch);
echo $userdata;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are passing `$request_headers` but the data you have in `$request_header` and better see your array is fine.

or may be try something like this:

```
$request_header[] = array('User-Agent'=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36',
'Content-Type'=> 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'onLoad'=>'[type Function]',
'p'=>'username',
'u'=>'password',
'owner'=>'[object Object]
');
```

Comment: I don't get a blank page, but stills dosen't make the request with the headers :/